# Groupby Year and other column and calculate average based on specific condition pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Tenancy_ID      Unit_ID             End_Date       Rental_value
1               A                   2012-04-26     10
2               A                   2012-08-27     20
3               A                   2013-04-27     50
4               A                   2014-04-27     40
1               B                   2011-06-26     10
2               B                   2011-09-27     30
3               B                   2013-04-27     60
4               B                   2015-04-27     80
```

From the above I would like to prepare below data frame

Expected Output:

```
Unit_ID   Avg_2011   Avg_2012  Avg_2013  Avg_2014   Avg_2015
A         NaN            15        50        40         NaN
B         20             NaN       60        NaN        80
```

Steps:

- Unit_ID = A, has two contracts in 2012 with rental value 10 and 20, Hence the average is 15.
- Avg_2012 = Average rental value in 2012.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groupby count based on year and specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909256/groupby-count-based-on-year-and-specific-condition)

Comment: it is the same with default aggfunc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggregate averages and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last data cleaning - [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Unit_ID', df['End_Date'].dt.year])['Rental_value']
         .mean()
         .unstack()
         .add_prefix('Avg_')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
  Unit_ID  Avg_2011  Avg_2012  Avg_2013  Avg_2014  Avg_2015
0       A       NaN      15.0      50.0      40.0       NaN
1       B      20.0       NaN      60.0       NaN      80.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) directly with the [`s.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html)

```
#df['End_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date']) if dtype of End_Date is not datetime

final = (df.pivot_table('Rental_value','Unit_ID',df['End_Date'].dt.year)
        .add_prefix('Avg_').reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

---

```
print(final)

  Unit_ID  Avg_2011  Avg_2012  Avg_2013  Avg_2014  Avg_2015
0       A       NaN      15.0      50.0      40.0       NaN
1       B      20.0       NaN      60.0       NaN      80.0
```

Comment: is it possible to accept both the answers? if then How? please guide me

Comment: @ALI no as of now that isn't possible :)